# One to many relation with composite key in many requires a primary key to be defined

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the following one to many table hierarchy in code first c#:

```
public class Head
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public static void CreateModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Head>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable(nameof(Head), schema: "dbo");
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);
            entity.Property(e => e.Id).IsRequired();
            entity.HasMany(c => c.Items).WithOne(e => e.Head);
        });
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public Guid HeadId { get; set; }
    public Head Head{ get; set; }
    public byte LanguageId { get; set; }
    public Language Language { get; set; }

    public static void CreateModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Item>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable(nameof(Item), schema: "dbo");
            entity.HasKey(e => new { e.HeadId, e.LanguageId });
            entity.Property(e => e.HeadId).IsRequired();
            entity.Property(e => e.LanguageId).IsRequired();
            entity.HasOne(e => e.Head).WithMany(e => e.Items);
            entity.HasOne(e => e.Language);
        });
    }
}
```

It creates the database table perfectly, but when I want to read data from it, I get this error:

> InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'Item' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'

Comment: You don't need any extra problem. Just add Id key to Item and make unique e.HeadId + e.LanguageId

Comment: Are you calling `Item.CreateModel(modelBuilder)` from your DbContext's `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)` method?